# Is it possible to use the report generator in pgadmin from command line?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

PgAdmin has the ability to generate reports (dependency report, data dictionary report) on a per table basis in the GUI. I need to be able to generate them for each of my tables - is it possible to do it via commmand line or otherwise batch create them for each of my tables?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no native way to do it using PgAdmin's command line.

Here is all what you can do using command line:

[PgAdmin 1.20](http://pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/commandline.html)

Comment: ok, thanks - Ive seen the docs before and was perhaps hoping that it  is an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pgquickreport` project, made by myself :)

https://github.com/carlosromel/pgquickreport

You can get same results by using a command line, like this:

```
java -jar pgquickreport.java queryfile.sql
```

The pgQuickReport will generate a file queryfile.html, pretty same result obtained by PgAdmin Quick Report.